# Google Keyword Relevancy

Tags: seo, google-search-console, keywords, search-results

I hope this is the correct place to ask this question. I've got a few websites going, so i'm ok with the usual terminology and have looked in SEO and tried to implement it as best i can on my sites. One thing i read is that Keywords are no longer really looked at or paid much attention by Google. So i have left Google to crawl my sites and let it figure out the Keywords for me. But on my Webmaster Tools Google page i can see all the Keywords it has found and ranked (great) but my question is how can i up the relevancy of some of the Keywords it has crawled? And is this going to have a positive effect on my SERP?

Any advice welcome thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible meanings to the way you use "keywords" in your question. One is the meta keywords tag, which you are correct Google does not take into account for relevancy purposes, the other would be keywords within the content of your site, those are still important to Google for determining relevancy.

That said if you're looking to rank for more relevant terms (IE you don't like what Google came up with) you should modify your content to be more geared toward those terms, if you're looking to increase your rankings for the keywords Google is suggesting are relevant then you might want to try link building.

Answer (score 1):

Joshak is mostly on-target, however, there's a missing piece of the puzzle there: Google factors in the words *used in links to your site* fairly heavily.

Review your top-rated keywords in Google Webmaster Tools and you'll very likely find the terms used in anchor text wherever someone links to your site.

Give people good reasons (compelling content, "sticky" features, etc) to your site with the keywords you want to rank well for in their links (i.e. `<a href="http://your-site.com/">Your Keywords</a>`) and you'll be well on your way to top rankings.

Answer (score 0):

Google puts great emphasis on keywords. Why do you think they even had Panda and Penguin in the first place? Keyword Density, Relevancy, and Anchor Text Density were a big indication for Google to detect optimized websites.

Don't let Google figure out your keywords. That is not the mark of a webmaster. You need Google to see your keywords the way that you want them to see.

The easiest way to build keyword relevancy is to build backlinks with those keywords as your anchor texts.

Comment: How does your answer add to the information already provided?